# Assertion Failed at method: gee_array_list_real_get

Tags: gtk, vala, libgee

I think I fixed this error but I want to be certain I did it the right way.
Also I am not sure why is it happening this way.

Code before fix:

```cs
private Gee.ArrayList<Gtk.Widget> menuButtons;

// Some other code here

public override void remove (Gtk.Widget widget) {
    if (widget in menuButtons) {
        widget.unparent ();
        menuButtons.remove ( widget ); // Look at this method call
        if (this.get_visible () && widget.get_visible ()) {
            this.queue_resize_no_redraw ();
        }
    }
}
```

The code causes:

```
ERROR:arraylist.c:957:gee_array_list_real_get: assertion failed: (index < _size)
./run: line 3: 11054 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./bin
```

Code after fix:

```cs
    private Gee.ArrayList<Gtk.Widget> menuButtons;

    // Some other code here

    public override void remove (Gtk.Widget widget) {
        if (widget in menuButtons) {
            widget.unparent ();
            if (this.get_visible () && widget.get_visible ()) {
                this.queue_resize_no_redraw ();
                menuButtons.remove ( widget ); // Moved method call here
            }
        }
    }
```

And now it works, I am not sure but it might be something to do with remove method being called asynchronously, is it?

Any good explanation?
Is it a correct fix of a problem?

@After checking the code again I am certain that it is not a correct fix of my problem because menuButtons.remove ( widget ); never gets called in my case. The widget stays in the list and that is unwanted behaviour.

MVCE:

MyContainer.vala

```cs
public class MyContainer : Gtk.Container {
  // ArrayList for storing menu buttons
  private Gee.ArrayList<Gtk.Widget> menuButtons;

  public MyContainer () {
    base.set_has_window (false);
    menuButtons = new Gee.ArrayList<Gtk.Widget> ();
  }

  public override void add (Gtk.Widget widget) {
    widget.set_parent (this);
    menuButtons.add (widget);
  }

  public override void remove (Gtk.Widget widget) {
    if (widget in menuButtons) {
      widget.unparent ();
      menuButtons.remove ( widget ); // After removing the widget from the List I get "assertion failed error"
      if (this.get_visible () && widget.get_visible ()) {
        this.queue_resize_no_redraw ();
      }
    }
  }

  public override void forall_internal (bool include_internals, Gtk.Callback callback) {
    foreach (var widget in menuButtons) {
      callback (widget);
    }
  }
}
```

SimpleGtkApplication.vala

```cs
public class SimpleGtkApplication : Gtk.Application {

  public SimpleGtkApplication () {
    Object (application_id: "simple.gtk.application", flags: ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE);
  }

  protected override void activate () {
    Gtk.ApplicationWindow window = new Gtk.ApplicationWindow (this);
    window.set_default_size (800, 600);
    window.title = "SimpleGtkApplication";

    Gtk.Container container = new MyContainer ();
    container.add ( new Gtk.Button.with_label ("Button 1") );
    container.add ( new Gtk.Button.with_label ("Button 2") );

    window.add ( container );
    window.show_all ();
  }

  public static int main (string[] args) {
    SimpleGtkApplication app = new SimpleGtkApplication ();
    return app.run (args);
  }

}
```

Compile with: `--pkg=gtk+-3.0 --pkg=gee-0.8`

Comment: Please expand your code to a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can compile and test.

Comment: Here is the github repository: https://github.com/andros705/Simple_Gtk_Application_With_Custom_Container

Comment: I have removed code nor relevant for an MVCE. If you run the program now and click the close button it will still trigger the assertion.

Comment: Is it a good idea to derive directly from `Gtk.Container`? What is it you are trying to do in the first place? You might want to add that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points:

1. You are overriding `Gtk.Container::remove`, but never chaining up to the parent class's implementation by calling `base.remove()`, which will cause you problems in the long run.
2. In `MyContainer::remove` you are calling `widget.unparent()`, which may be causing some kind of secondary invocation of `MyContainer::remove`. If so, both times the `widget in menuButtons` test evaluates to true, but when the original invocation tries to remove the widget from the list, it's already gone, hence the assertion failure.

TL;DR: Replace the call to `widget.unparent()` with `base.remove(widget)`.

PS: I'd be really suprised if you need the explicit `this.queue_resize_no_redraw()` call either, GTK+ really should be managing that for you.

Comment: I updated the code on GitHub according to your points but I am still getting this awful assertion error + one new warning " Gtk-WARNING **: GtkContainerClass::remove not implemented for 'MyContainer' "

GitHub link: https://github.com/andros705/Simple_Gtk_Application_With_Custom_Container

Comment: That warning might be due to some missing functionality. If you derive from `Gtk.Box` instead of `Gtk.Container` it goes away.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael wrote, you are doing a lot of the things that Gtk could do for you yourself. You are also not calling the base methods in your overrides.

You are directly deriving from `Gtk.Container`, I have adapted your MVCE to use a `Gtk.Box` instead and get no warnings and no assertions with this code:

```cs
public class MyContainer : Gtk.Box {
  private Gee.ArrayList<Gtk.Widget> menuButtons;

  public MyContainer () {
    menuButtons = new Gee.ArrayList<Gtk.Widget> ();
  }

  public override void add (Gtk.Widget widget) {
    base.add (widget);
    menuButtons.add (widget);
  }

  public override void remove (Gtk.Widget widget) {
    if (widget in menuButtons) {
      menuButtons.remove (widget);
    }
    base.remove (widget);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok well, I was actually pretty much following this documentation: https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Container.html but thanks I am going to try your way

Comment: You should have mentioned that earlier. If you want people to be as helpful as possible you should add all background information that you have. BTW I'm by no means an expert on Gtk+.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that was a very important information.
Seems that Gtk.Box contains a lot of code that I simply don't need.
And it doesn't give the flexibility at would need, breaking the whole app design.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you want to achieve then. A good question oft has an introduction paragraph with background information. It is of course possible to derive from `Gtk.Container` directly. I have personally never done that though. I think that this is developing into a different topic now.

Comment: I will try to achieve my thing using Gtk.Box but I would also like to know how to fix the Gtk.Container version.